# CDK -- how to access subnets that are created with PrivateSubnet construct

Tags: aws-cdk

I am new to CDK..please help me with figuring out the issue below.

I created 3 subnets outside of the VPC construct via PrivateSubnet construct, please see below.

```py
    private_subnets=[]
    for az in az_list:
        priv_subnet = ec2.PrivateSubnet(self, "id-{k}",
            availability_zone= az,
            cidr_block=v,
            vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
            map_public_ip_on_launch= False,
        )
        private_subnets.append(priv_subnet.subnet_id)
```

I am trying to consume subnet ids this way:

```py
         for subnetid in private_subnets:      
            nat_gateway = ec2.CfnNatGateway(self, f"NatGateway-{subnetid}",
                subnet_id=subnetid,
                connectivity_type= "private"
            )
```

I need to refer to subnet ids in another construct I am trying to create and I am running in to an unresolved token issue.

How can I refer to the subnet ids that were created as part of the code above?

I tried cdk synth or cdk deploy to get runtime value of subnet ids, I still got unresolved token error.

Comment: How are you consuming the subnet IDs?  Please add another code block to your question to show this.

Comment: @fedonev thanks so much, I added another block on how I am trying to consume the subnets ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subnet_id` value is a [token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) placeholder.  Its value is resolved cloud-side only later, at deploy-time.  We can't treat it exactly like a regular string value.  One constraint is that the `subnet_id` token value can't be used in a construct ID, which is causing your error.

One solution is to build a list of two-element tuples, rather than a list of `subnet_id`. The tuple has the AZ name (string) and the subnet construct object itself.<sup>*</sup>

```py
private_subnets: list[tuple[str, ec2.PrivateSubnet]] = []

for az in azs:
    priv_subnet = ec2.PrivateSubnet( ... )
    private_subnets.append((az, priv_subnet))
```

Consume the tuple to build the private NAT Gateways.

```py
for (az, priv_subnet) in private_subnets:
    ec2.CfnNatGateway(
        self,
        f"NatGateway-{az}",
        subnet_id=priv_subnet.subnet_id,
        connectivity_type="private",
    )
```

*  I find putting the subnet object in the tuple [to be clearer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_attributes) than passing just the `subnet_id` tokens.  However, your approach of putting the `subnet_id` tokens is the list (i.e. `private_subnets: list[tuple[str, str]]`) will also work. Just don't use the `subnet_id` in the construct ID.